# How to get objct information from Ajax response in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, django

I'm working on a site that needs to parse an Ajax response which looks something like this:

```
{"comments": "[{\"model\": \"modelhandler.comment\", \"pk\": 4, \"fields\": {\"user\": 2, \"description\": \"hello this is a comment but I don't know if it's working yet.......\", \"replyto\": null, \"uploaded\": \"2018-01-10T20:35:40.856Z\", \"updated\": \"2018-01-10T20:35:40.856Z\"}}]"}
```

I tried getting data from this response like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    $.each(json, function(key,value) {
        alert(value.comments);
    });
}
```

This however alerts me `undefined`

Here the comments field has 1 comment in it but I might have more than 1. How would I go about retrieving data from a Json response like this?

EDIT:

I logged `data` object and I got this:

```
Object
comments
:
"[{"model": "modelhandler.comment", "pk": 4, "fields": {"user": 2, "description": "hello this is a comment but I din't know if it's working yet.......", "replyto": null, "uploaded": "2018-01-10T20:35:40.856Z", "updated": "2018-01-10T20:35:40.856Z"}}]"
__proto__
:
Object
```

in Google Chrome using console.log()

also the json is generated by a django view like this:

```
def obtain_comments(request, *args, **kwargs):
    begin = int(request.GET['begin'])
    end = int(request.GET['end'])
    n_comments = end - begin
    all_split = Comment.objects.order_by('-uploaded')[:end]
    data = {
        'comments': serializers.serialize('json',all_split),
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: I don't understand this: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`.  Why are you stringifying only to parse immediately?

Comment: drop `stringify`; that's used to convert something that's already parsed JSON into a string. You just want `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: now that I removed the stringefy i get: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`

Comment: Try logging `data`, what does it look like? It probably isn't what you expect. You can `JSON.stringify()` almost anything and then `JSON.parse()` it without an error, that doesn't mean you're getting meaningful data out of it though.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette while some of the answers may apply, this is not a duplicate of that question

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I don't think so as I am using django...

Comment: Okay.. I retracted the close vote.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Django is Python... Not PHP. I made the same assumption.

Comment: oops didnt noticed the `django` tag @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam: sure.. I just added it. ;)

Comment: ROFL , you are cheeky :D

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette lol sorry thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your response is an object and values are stringified.

Try

```
success: function (data) {
  var comments = JSON.parse(data.comments);
  // comments is an array now
  comments.forEach(function(comment) {
    console.log(comment.fields.description);
  });
}
```

It would be better if you were to serialize entire data object in Django instead of just comments.

Comment: the way here seems to work but I now have each array element like `Object { model: "modelhandler.comment", pk: 4, fields: Object }` how would I go about accessing one of it's field?

Comment: NVM found it: 'console.log(json[0].fields.description)'

Comment: Try `console.log(comments[0].model);`... It should print `modelhandler.comment` You now have an array of objects.